# Return the SQL Statement of an Explicit Cursor

Tags: sql, oracle, sys-refcursor

Taking the example shown in Oracle Forums: [Generating excel(xls) using plsql](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2544010), i would like to generate an excel file from a query's data set.

The example provided there works. however, there are some challenges i'm encountering:

1. My SQL query is quite long and exceeds the `VARCHAR2` 4000 Character limitation.
2. I would like to pass parameters to my query.
3. I would like to do it in a very simple manner and without using Dynamic SQL (if possible).

What I've come up is something like below:

**Package Definition:**

```
create or replace package tabletoexcel
as

  PROCEDURE run_query(p_fh  IN UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE
                    , p_cur IN SYS_REFCURSOR);
  PROCEDURE start_workbook (p_fh  IN UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE);
  PROCEDURE end_workbook (p_fh  IN UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE);
  PROCEDURE start_worksheet(p_fh        IN UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE
                         ,  p_sheetname IN VARCHAR2);
  PROCEDURE end_worksheet (p_fh  IN UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE);
  PROCEDURE set_date_style (p_fh  IN UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE);

end tabletoexcel;  

create or replace package body tabletoexcel
as

  PROCEDURE run_query(p_fh    UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE
                    , p_sql IN VARCHAR2) IS
    v_v_val     VARCHAR2(4000);
    v_n_val     NUMBER;
    v_d_val     DATE;
    v_ret       NUMBER;
    c           NUMBER;
    d           NUMBER;
    col_cnt     INTEGER;
    f           BOOLEAN;
    rec_tab     DBMS_SQL.DESC_TAB;
    col_num     NUMBER;
  BEGIN
    c := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
    -- parse the SQL statement
    DBMS_SQL.PARSE(c, p_sql, DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);
    -- start execution of the SQL statement
    d := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(c);
    -- get a description of the returned columns
    DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS(c, col_cnt, rec_tab);

    -- bind variables to columns
    FOR j in 1..col_cnt
    LOOP
      CASE rec_tab(j).col_type
        WHEN 1 THEN DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(c,j,v_v_val,4000);
        WHEN 2 THEN DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(c,j,v_n_val);
        WHEN 12 THEN DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(c,j,v_d_val);
      ELSE
        DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(c,j,v_v_val,4000);
      END CASE;
    END LOOP;

    -- Output the column headers
    UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(gv_file_type,'<ss:Row>');
    FOR j in 1..col_cnt
    LOOP
      UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(gv_file_type,'<ss:Cell>');
      UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(gv_file_type,'<ss:Data ss:Type="String">'||rec_tab(j).col_name||'</ss:Data>');
      UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(gv_file_type,'</ss:Cell>');
    END LOOP;
    UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(gv_file_type,'</ss:Row>');

    -- Output the data
    LOOP
      v_ret := DBMS_SQL.FETCH_ROWS(c);
      EXIT WHEN v_ret = 0;
      UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(gv_file_type,'<ss:Row>');
      FOR j in 1..col_cnt
      LOOP
        CASE rec_tab(j).col_type
          WHEN 1 THEN DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(c,j,v_v_val);
                      UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(gv_file_type,'<ss:Cell>');
                      UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(gv_file_type,'<ss:Data ss:Type="String">'||v_v_val||'</ss:Data>');
                      UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(gv_file_type,'</ss:Cell>');
          WHEN 2 THEN DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(c,j,v_n_val);
                      UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(gv_file_type,'<ss:Cell>');
                      UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(gv_file_type,'<ss:Data ss:Type="Number">'||to_char(v_n_val)||'</ss:Data>');
                      UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(gv_file_type,'</ss:Cell>');
          WHEN 12 THEN DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(c,j,v_d_val);
                      UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(gv_file_type,'<ss:Cell ss:StyleID="OracleDate">');
                      UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(gv_file_type,'<ss:Data ss:Type="DateTime">'||to_char(v_d_val,'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS')||'</ss:Data>');
                      UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(gv_file_type,'</ss:Cell>');
        ELSE
          DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(c,j,v_v_val);
          UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(gv_file_type,'<ss:Cell>');
          UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(gv_file_type,'<ss:Data ss:Type="String">'||v_v_val||'</ss:Data>');
          UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(gv_file_type,'</ss:Cell>');
        END CASE;
      END LOOP;
      UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(gv_file_type,'</ss:Row>');
    END LOOP;
    DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(c);
  END run_query;

  PROCEDURE start_workbook (p_fh    UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE) IS
  BEGIN
    UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(gv_file_type,'<?xml version="1.0"?>');
    UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(gv_file_type,'<ss:Workbook xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">');
  END start_workbook;

  PROCEDURE end_workbook (p_fh    UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE) IS
  BEGIN
    UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(gv_file_type,'</ss:Workbook>');
  END end_workbook;
  --
  PROCEDURE start_worksheet(p_fh    UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE
                        ,   p_sheetname IN VARCHAR2) IS
  BEGIN
    UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(gv_file_type,'<ss:Worksheet ss:Name="'||p_sheetname||'">');
    UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(gv_file_type,'<ss:Table>');
  END start_worksheet;

  PROCEDURE end_worksheet (p_fh    UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE) IS
  BEGIN
    UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(gv_file_type,'</ss:Table>');
    UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(gv_file_type,'</ss:Worksheet>');
  END end_worksheet;
  --
  PROCEDURE set_date_style (p_fh    UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE) IS
  BEGIN
    UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(gv_file_type,'<ss:Styles>');
    UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(gv_file_type,'<ss:Style ss:ID="OracleDate">');
    UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(gv_file_type,'<ss:NumberFormat ss:Format="dd/mm/yyyy\ hh:mm:ss"/>');
    UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(gv_file_type,'</ss:Style>');
    UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(gv_file_type,'</ss:Styles>');
  END set_date_style;

end tabletoexcel;
```

now, my anonymous block would be preferably something like below **(please take note of the comments)**:

```
declare

    l_fh            UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
    l_directory     VARCHAR2(30) := 'EMPLOYEE_FILE_DIR';
    l_filename      VARCHAR2(30) := 'myfile.xls';    
    l_sql_statement VARCHAR2(4000);    

    Cursor emp_cur (p_emp_no     varchar2
                   ,p_payroll_id number
                   ,p_bg_id      number)
    is
    select  *
    from    table_a
    where   employee_number     = nvl(p_emp_no, employee_number)
    and     payroll_id          = nvl(p_payroll_id, payroll_id);
    and     business_group_id   = p_bg_id
    -- This is the Really really long query but i just placed Table_A for Sample Purposes

BEGIN

    l_fh := UTl_file.FOPEN(upper(l_directory),l_filename,'w',32767);
    tabletoexcel.start_workbook (l_fh);
    tabletoexcel.set_date_style (l_fh);
    tabletoexcel.start_worksheet(l_fh, 'EMP');

    tabletoexcel.run_query(emp_cur('1', 2, 3));
    -- I'm sure this won't work, but i would like to pass something simple as this.

    tabletoexcel.end_worksheet (l_fh);
    tabletoexcel.end_workbook (l_fh);
    UTl_file.FCLOSE(l_fh);

END;
```

Is it possible to pass an explicit cursor definition to a `DBMS_SQL` package?
I'm thinking a Built-In Function that Returns the SQL Statement of an Explicit Cursor would solve this problem. Perhaps a Ref Cursor?

Comment: Well, using `DBMS_SQL` package is them "most dynamic" SQL you can have. Try `OPEN cur FOR ...`, as far as I know the statement can be even a CLOB.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, would it be possible to use  `DBMS_SQL.to_cursor_number` for this? if so, how can i pass explicit cursors to `DBMS_SQL.to_cursor_number`? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do that with [DBMS_SQL.TO_CURSOR_NUMBER](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sql.htm#ARPLS68279) function. You Procedure will look like this:

```
PROCEDURE run_query(p_cur IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) IS
    ...
BEGIN

    c := DBMS_SQL.TO_CURSOR_NUMBER(p_cur);

    -- get a description of the returned columns
    DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS(c, col_cnt, rec_tab);
    ...
```

Then you have to call it like this:

```
declare

    l_cur SYS_REFCURSOR;

BEGIN

    OPEN l_cur FOR
       select  *
       from    table_a
       where   employee_number     = nvl(p_emp_no, employee_number)
       and     payroll_id          = nvl(p_payroll_id, payroll_id);
       and     business_group_id   = p_bg_id
       ...;

    tabletoexcel.run_query(l_cur);
```

[OPEN FOR](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/openfor_statement.htm#LNPLS01333) Statement allows `CLOB` as statement, so there is no practical limit in terms of size.

Since you don't know at design time which columns will be selected (at least I assume so) there is no way to get rid of `DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS` and `DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN`. Otherwise you can use [FETCH Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/fetch_statement.htm#LNPLS01320) instead of `DBMS_SQL.FETCH_ROWS(c)`

Comment: thank you! this worked for me. i got the error `cannot use p_cur as an assignment operator`. i passed it to a local variable `l_cur := p_cur;` to make it work.

Comment: Yes, I missed that. `run_query(p_cur IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)` should do the same.